# CPU high load and free ram

Tags: server, load, cloud, cpu, ram

I have a cloud server in cloudways, the CPU load is very high even after I upgrade my server up 2 levels but the strange thing is the ram is almost free ( server 16 GB ram 6 Core) is there anything we can do to take advantage of that free ram to reduce CPU load.

Regards

Comment: the web host told me it's the high traffic, and it's true i receive more traffic this days

Answer (score 1):

No CPU and RAM are different things

- Check the reason why your CPU is highly loaded.
- Maybe your host where your VM runs on is overloaded. Did you try to
  contact your cloud provider?

Comment: the web host told me it's the high traffic, and it's true i receive more traffic this days